# TypeError with model field

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I add some new fields in model and django suggested me to add default value or set some default params in model. I added datetime object as value, but the value should be the int or number. Now I can't sync db becouse of type error. I tried to delete some objects which was instances of this model, where I did some changes but It doesn't help me.

How I can fix my model now?!

this is traceback

```
Applying card.0026_auto_20150104_1323...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.p
y", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.p
y", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\s
yncdb.py", line 27, in handle_noargs
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.p
y", line 115, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\m
igrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py"
, line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py"
, line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py
", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, ne
w_state)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\f
ields.py", line 37, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema
.py", line 167, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema
.py", line 74, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\schema.py", li
ne 184, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.p
y", line 1735, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.related_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.
py", line 627, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.
py", line 907, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\RIK\Envs\la\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.
py", line 915, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

this is part of model code:

I added owner field in CollectionItem object:

```
class CollectionItem (models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card)
    golden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='collectionCards')

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.card.price



class Collection (models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='collections')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CollectionItem, through='CollectionCollector')


class CollectionAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['owner'] admin.site.register(Collection, CollectionAdmin)

class CollectionCollector (models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(CollectionItem, related_name='collection_item')
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
```

Comment: It will help to see the code that generated the errors.

Comment: It is just a syncdb command in command line. All code was warking. Now I can run server. But code doesn't see new fields which I added early and I cant sync db becouse of this error.

Comment: argument `value` is `datetime.datetime` type which cannot be converted to `int`, but as @Joel said we need to see the code.

Comment: I think I need to drop field owner in database how I can do this?!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you gave `datetime.datetime.now()` as default values during migrations as it asked you to enter.

just edit the migration files and change the datetime default value to string for one of these fields

```
count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
level = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

then run migrate again

Comment: thank you so much. I found the wrong datetime default value in migration hystory and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same sitution in my enviroment , and here are the solutions what i take:
remove **db.sqlite3** 
remove all **migrations file** in all app
then rerun comments:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After these steps,no error appears again.
I also find a similar solution link in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34825277/6711680

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old python files in migration folder in your app directory and then migrate again. It will fix the issues.