# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am attempting to add a 'created_at' field for all my models and am getting the following error... 
`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'`

***In order, this is my work flow...***
1) I put `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` in my models.
2) I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and it displays the following prompt in my command line...

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'created_at' to comment without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
```

3) At this point I type in `timezone.now()` on all of the models and when finished it successfully creates the migrations file for me.

4) I run `python manage.py migrate` and get the `TypeError` message displayed above.

**Things I have tried...**

1) Looking through Stack Overflow for similar issues (to no avail)...
2) Deleteing the migrations file and attempting to use `datetime.datetime.now()` 
3) Deleteing the migrations file and attempting to use the simple integer `1`.

All of these attempts have been fruitless.

***Full command line traceback...***

```
(env)alopex@Alopex:~/repos/hacker_news$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, sessions, hackernews, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying hackernews.0003_auto_20151226_1701...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 382, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 910, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 968, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/alopex/repos/hacker_news/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

***Full migration file...***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9 on 2015-12-26 17:01
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
from django.utils.timezone import utc


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ('hackernews', '0002_auto_20151224_1605'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='comment',
        name='created_at',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 23, 211181, tzinfo=utc)),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='comment',
        name='user',
        field=models.ForeignKey(default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 28, 128127, tzinfo=utc), on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='commentvote',
        name='created_at',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 34, 85491, tzinfo=utc)),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='post',
        name='created_at',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 37, 779457, tzinfo=utc)),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='postvote',
        name='created_at',
        field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 41, 794803, tzinfo=utc)),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the new `ForeignKey`:

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='comment',
    name='user',
    field=models.ForeignKey(default=datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 26, 17, 1, 28, 128127, tzinfo=utc), on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    preserve_default=False,
),
```

Clearly the default value is wrong. I think you have inserted it by mistake.

You should either specify the primary key of a user, or give a `User` object.

Comment: where did you add thhis?

Answer (score 6):

***I fixed this in a very clean way. Here is what you need to do***

- Go to migrations folder and search for the migration file of the model you want to migrate. you will find that, it has a default set to `timezone.now`
- Change that to no default(remove the `default` config) and set `null=True blank=True`
- Run `python manage.py migrate`

And that should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar problem and I would like to share how I solved this as it may be of benefit to others. This was a challenge to solve with little specific information from the Django documentation and this thread appears to be the best-phrased question on stackoverflow.

My situation:

- I am new to Django and experimenting, and using the SQLLite database model
- I had created a simple model, and during the migrate is asked the question about providing a one-off default, which I provided
- From this point on the migrate process would not forget this default, and I could not migrate this further and was stuck

My solution:

- Given that I am not in production and also not in large-scale development I adopted the approach to kill the database and all of the migrations and then to migrate again, which solved the problem
- NOTE: If you have vested data in the database, then back up the data first or seek other guidance - there are other threads which show how to do this backup and restore, even between database management systems
- under the project root, look for the file **db.sqlite3** and rename or delete this which will force this to be recreated on the next migrate
- under the **migrations** folder delete ALL of the migrations **.py** files - this will prevent these from being applied again when the database is recreated
- run migrate again - which will create a clean database without attempting to reinstate the default

I accept that my approach is a bit of a hack but it worked for me, and also without any damage to my models which were all created perfectly - I did also fix the lack of the default which was causing the problem which was a mistake of mine in entering a char default for an integer field. However, there may be side-effects if you are further into your development and I would welcome suggestions on a safer approach to this problem.

Comment: This is actually the best answer, I have to delete all the migration file before mine worked

Answer (score 3):

None of those solutions work for me. But when I **removed** all files from *migrations* folder in my app folder in project and ran `python manage.py migrate`, everything worked fine and there were no more problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem, I have tried as suggested above and I deleted only my migration file which is causing this issue (latest file created while applying `python manage.py makemigrations`), again I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, here I notice that previously I have given `>>> timezone.now()` as default for ForeignKey Field, this time I have set default value in my models.py file and my problem was  solved.

Note: don't provide default values for ForeignKeys while migrating.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when i opened not migrated file and on ForeignKey i separated the values null=True, blank=True with the comma in between.

field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, blank=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='your_app.Model')